# Como muestro los dos primeros elementos de una lista en ProLog

Tags: prolog, inteligencia-artificial, lógica

Lo único que hice hasta el momento es ingresar la lista. No se como hacer para que muestre los dos primeros elementos de una lista.

```
  inicio:-write('Ingrese una lista de elementos: '),leer([A|B]),
  write('El primer elemento de la lista es: '),write(H),
  write('El segundo elemento de la lista es: '),write(.

  leer([H|T]):-read(H),H\=[],leer(T).

  leer([]).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr lo que quieres debes de tomar en cuenta primero la definición recursiva de las listas en prolog, es decir, .

```
[] % lista vacía
[H] % Lista con un elemento
[HT] % lista con cabeza y una lista que es la cola [H[T]]
[HST] % lista con cabeza y resto que es una lista compuesta de dos elementos
% [H[ST]] que es lo mismo que decir [H[S[T]]]
```

Otro elemento que tal vez no hayas visto es que cuando alguna variable es trivial, es decir no es relevante ya que no vas a usarla para nada y para ello pones el caracter `_` como nombre de esa variable.

Ahora veamos que le cambié.

```
,leer([Primero|RestoDeLaLista])
```

Nada mágico acá, un simple cambio de nombre de las variables para hacertelo más entendible.

```
RestoDeLaLista=[Segundo,_]
```

En esa línea está lo importante, estoy diciendo que el resto de la lista se compone de un elemento que es el segundo y que lo demás es trivial, (osea que me da igual lo que sea).

## Programa

```
inicio:-
  writeln('Ingrese una lista de elementos: ')
  ,nl
  ,writeln('Escriba [] para dejar de leer elementos')
  ,leer([Primero|RestoDeLaLista]),
  writeln('El primer elemento de la lista es: ')
  , RestoDeLaLista=[Segundo,_]
  ,write(Primero)
  ,nl
  ,writeln('El segundo elemento de la lista es: ')
  ,writeln(Segundo)
  ,nl
.

leer([H|T]):-
   writeln('Escribe un elemento y luego pon un punto')
   , read(H)
   ,H\=[]
   ,leer(T).
   leer([]).
```